# Dynamically loaded imagemaps in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, imagemap, imagemapster

I have proof of concept imagemap code using angularjs [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ABNlw9ifHRFtj3FB7Yd?p=preview).

I am writing something to behave the same as the jquery example that I put together [here](http://wdenet.com/imapster/index_jq.html).

You'll note in the first example doesn't work because the imagemap is being populated by a scope variable, so on page load the image src is a 404.  This prevents the imagemap from activating at all.  I would really appreciate help understanding how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used the $timeout service to wait for the DOM to be rendered as described here: [Slick Carousel with Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523367/slick-carousel-with-angular-js)

However, I needed to specify an actual timeout value as the default didn't work in my case (for both slick and mapster)

Comment: I ended up using recursion to wait on objects to render. The technique is described here: http://buzzdecafe.github.io/2014/03/20/directive-after-dom/