# Slick Carousel in angular js on json data not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I user this programme [github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick](http://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick). it is not working with dynamic data. it work only with static data. In dynamic data it show vertical image insted of horizontal with no Carouseling .Please help me.
here is my diractive

```
directive('slick',function($timeout) {  return {
restrict: "AEC",
scope: {
  initOnload: "@",
  data: "=",
  currentIndex: "=",
  accessibility: "@",
  arrows: "@",
  autoplay: "@",
  autoplaySpeed: "@",
  centerMode: "@",
  centerPadding: "@",
  cssEase: "@",
  dots: "@",
  draggable: "@",
  easing: "@",
  fade: "@",
  infinite: "@",
  lazyLoad: "@",
  onBeforeChange: "@",
  onAfterChange: "@",
  onInit: "@",
  onReInit: "@",
  pauseOnHover: "@",
  responsive: "&",
  slide: "@",
  slidesToShow: "@",
  slidesToScroll: "@",
  speed: "@",
  swipe: "@",
  touchMove: "@",
  touchThreshold: "@",
  vertical: "@"
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var initializeSlick, isInitialized;
  initializeSlick = function() {
    return $timeout(function() {
      var currentIndex, slider;
      slider = $(element);
      if (scope.currentIndex != null) {
        currentIndex = scope.currentIndex;
      }
      slider.slick({
        accessibility: scope.accessibility !== "false",
        arrows: scope.arrows !== "false",
        autoplay: scope.autoplay === "true",
        autoplaySpeed: scope.autoplaySpeed != null ? parseInt(scope.autoplaySpeed, 10) : 3000,
        centerMode: scope.centerMode === "true",
        centerPadding: scope.centerPadding || "50px",
        cssEase: scope.cssEase || "ease",
        dots: scope.dots === "true",
        draggable: scope.draggable !== "false",
        easing: scope.easing || "linear",
        fade: scope.fade === "true",
        infinite: scope.infinite !== "false",
        lazyLoad: scope.lazyLoad || "ondemand",
        onBeforeChange: scope.onBeforeChange || null,
        onAfterChange: function(sl, index) {
          if (scope.onAfterChange) {
            scope.onAfterChange();
          }
          if (currentIndex != null) {
            return scope.$apply(function() {
              currentIndex = index;
              return scope.currentIndex = index;
            });
          }
        },
        onInit: function(sl) {
          if (scope.onInit) {
            scope.onInit();
          }
          if (currentIndex != null) {
            return sl.slideHandler(currentIndex);
          }
        },
        onReInit: scope.onReInit || null,
        pauseOnHover: scope.pauseOnHover !== "false",
        responsive: scope.responsive() || null,
        slide: scope.slide || "div",
        slidesToShow: scope.slidesToShow != null ? parseInt(scope.slidesToShow, 10) : 1,
        slidesToScroll: scope.slidesToScroll != null ? parseInt(scope.slidesToScroll, 10) : 1,
        speed: scope.speed != null ? parseInt(scope.speed, 10) : 300,
        swipe: scope.swipe !== "false",
        touchMove: scope.touchMove !== "false",
        touchThreshold: scope.touchThreshold ? parseInt(scope.touchThreshold, 10) : 5,
        vertical: scope.vertical === "true"
      });
      return scope.$watch("currentIndex", function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if ((currentIndex != null) && (newVal != null) && newVal !== currentIndex) {
          return slider.slickGoTo(newVal);
        }
      });
    });
  };
  if (scope.initOnload) {
    isInitialized = false;
    return scope.$watch("data", function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if ((newVal != null) && !isInitialized) {
        initializeSlick();
        return isInitialized = true;
      }
    });
  } else {
    return initializeSlick();
  }
}  };});
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please. Its hard to debug like this

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

There's an attribute called init-onLoad, just make it true.

```
<slick init-onload=true data="awesomeThings">
  ...
</slick>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case using below settings didn't work for you.

> init-onload=true data="awesomeThings"

Use this instead.

> ng-if="awesomeThings.length"